Any tool out there to force a resolution to NOT fit to a display?
Came across a Wega Trinitron recently, lovely thing.
Hooked up my rig to it for personal satisfaction and ran into issues with Overscan on it
If anyone knows of a program or config settings to not force a chosen resolution to meet the edges of a display, I'd like to know. not particularly savvy with Linux and not the most patient with digging for answers on my own

That is an issue to address with the maker of the Wega not a Ubuntu issue. Nothing in the Ubuntu OS is going to force the TV to do anything.
